# jQuery $.ajax-Function - load iframe vimeo video

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, vimeo

Hey guys I tried to change my content in this way:

```
$("ul#nav li a").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("id"); //getID in a String

    getContent(href);

    $("ul#nav li a").removeClass("active"); //Active
    var select = $("#" + href);
    select.addClass("active");
});

//getContent --- URL aufrufen
function getContent(href) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        //url: href + ".html",
        //url : "http://localhost/ProVid/" + href + ".html",
        url: "http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~lieneman/pages/" + href + ".html",
        //url: "http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~lieneman/pages/vorstellung.html",
        dataType : "html",

        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        },
        success : parseHTML,
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            $('#content').html("<h3 style='text-align: center;'>Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten</h3>");
        }
    });
}

function parseHTML(html) {
    content = $(html).filter("#content").text();
    titel = $(html).filter("#title").text();
    video = $(html).filter("#video").text();

    $("#content").html(content);
    $("#title").html(titel);
    $("#video").html(video);
}
```

It is only working for normal HTML content. But I want to load in a vimeo video (iFrame).

Der Nachbereitungs-Baustein

Answer (score 2):

Check your console, do you see anything along the lines of:

> Refused to display 'http://vimeo.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Vimeo are actively trying to prevent their site from be displayed in an iframe by adding this header to all their responses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

**EDIT**:
I see that their standard embed code uses an iframe, for which they obviously don't apply this restriction, so if that is what you are using then this won't be the cause of your problem.